# How to add an event with content to a non-default google calendar?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have refer to http://www.pauldeden.com/2009/01/creating-application-to-insert-events.html to add an quick event with title and time but without content to a non-default google calendar using python.

if i use

```
event.content = atom.data.Content(text=content)
```

to give content to the event,the console of Ubuntu says:

```
AttributeError:'Content' object has no attribute '_BecomeChildElement'
```

What does it mean?How to solve it?

Comment: what's the full code of your event ?
Have you check the doc http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#CreatingEvents Without the full code I can't say what's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would need your code to be sure, but I believe you are not creating the variable content correctly. 
You should be careful to make sure that content is of type content when initializing it. Maybe you are just using it as a string?

With your code I can provide a better answer.

Have you tried with the new v3 API? It is very simple.

```
created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
    calendarId='primary',
    text='Appointment at Somewhere on June 3rd 10am-10:25am').execute()

print created_event['id']
```